# Optimal time to renew a library book

Tags: probability, optimization, discrete-optimization

A real world word problem from my life:

I often check out books and DVDs from my local library. The standard check-out period is three weeks. Using the library's website, I can renew any checked out item at any time before it's due to extend the due date to three weeks after the time of renewal. I am allowed to renew an item twice before I must return it.

This encourages me to renew items only when they are near their due dates so that I can get the maximum amount of time with my items before running out of renewals. However, the rule is I can't renew an item if another library patron places a hold on it. If someone does, I must return the item by its current due date. This encourages me to renew items early before anybody has a chance to place a hold on it.

So if I renew too early, I won't extend the initial three week check-out period by very much. If I renew too late, my item has a greater chance of acquiring a hold, in which case I won't extend the initial check-out period at all.

So that leads to the following question: When during a given three week check-out period is the best time for me to renew an item so that I can keep the item for the longest possible time with the lowest risk that a hold will be placed on it before I can renew?

I suppose we may assume the probability on any given day that a checked-out item of mine will get a hold placed on it is constant and independent of which day it is during the three week period. Beyond that I have no idea what the actual *value* of that probability is, except that I know from experience that, for a popular item, it is pretty likely that a hold will get placed on it within, say, $10$ days after I check it out.

I'd be interested if anyone can answer my question in general where the probability per day of a hold is $p$. Intuitively, if $p$ is small, then I should renew late; if $p$ is large, then I should renew early.

Additionally, I'm also interested if anyone can offer some good estimates of what $p$ might actually *be* either using my own (very rough) description, or their own experience or analysis.

Comment: if you don't renew, your expected days is 21.  if you renew after n days, then you have a $(1 - p)^n$ chance of increasing your expected days by n, making the expected days $21 + n(1 - p)^n$ - so for 1 renewal, you could start by maximising that - for the 1 renewal case, and a 10% daily chance of reservation, I got about 10 as the answer

Comment: @Cato: Could you explain a little more what the expression $21 + n(1-p)^n$ represents? My probability knowledge is rusty, but based on your comment, if I let the random variable $N$ denote the number of days before a hold gets placed, then, as you say, $P(N=n) = (1-p)^n$. In which case, the expected number of days before a hold is $E[N] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^n = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$. Maybe this is the answer? But if so, I'd like an explanation as to why it truly is the *optimal* number of days. As such, it just represents the mean number of days until a hold will get placed.

Answer (score 1):

First assume that I may extend only once by $n$ days.

If I have held the item for $1\le k\le n$ days (since the beginning or my last successfull renewal), and I try to extend, then this will succeed with probability $(1-p)^k$ and hence my total time (since the beginning or my last successfull renewal) will be $=n+k$ with probability $(1-p)^k$ and $=n$ with probability $1-(1-p)^k$. Hence the expected value is $n+k(1-p)^k$, and I want to maximize this. Clearly, $k+1$ is better than $k$ iff $(k+1)(1-p)^{k+1}>k(1-p)^k$, i.e., $k<\frac1p-1$. Hence the (or a) best $k$ is

- $ k=\left\lceil\frac1p-1\right\rceil$ if this is valid, i.e., if $\frac1{n+1}\le p<1$
- $k=n$ if $p<\frac1{n}$
- irrelevant if $p=1$

In other words, $k$ is given by $\frac1{k+1}\le p<\frac1k$ if possible.

At any rate, this will give me an expected time of $n'= n+k(1-p)^k$.
Note that if the optimal $k$ is $\gg1$ (and $p$ not much smaller than $\frac1n$) then we will have $n'\approx n+\frac ke$.

Next assume we still have two attempts to extend by $n$ days available.
If I have held the item for $1\le k'\le n$ days and try to extend, this will again succeed with $(1-p)^{k'}$. but as the extension will be $n'$ (in expectation9 instead of just $n$, the total expected lease time will be
$n$ with probability $1-(1-p)^{k'}$ and $k'+n'=n+k'+k(1-p)^k$ with probability $(1-p)^{k'}$, i.e., 
$$n+(1-p)^{k'}(k'+k(1-p)^k). $$ 
This time, $k'+1$ is better than $k'$ iff 
$ \frac1p-1-k(1-p)^k>k'$.
Hence we will pick
$$k'=\left\lceil \frac1p-1-\left\lceil\frac1p-1\right\rceil^{\vphantom|}(1-p)^{\left\lceil\frac1p-1\right\rceil}\right\rceil $$
for "moderate" $p$, but 
$$ k'=\min\left\{\left\lceil\frac1p-1-n(1-p)^n\right\rceil,n\right\} $$
for small $p<\frac1n$.

Comment: I think I understand most of your post. But I don't understand what the "expected value" expression ($n+k(1-p)^k$) represents or how you derived it or why the maximum of this function provides the optimal renewal day. My own limited understanding of probability is the expected value of a random variable $X$ is $\sum_k k P(X=k)$, which is similar to the expression you provide, except there is no sigma sum. Can you please explain further?

Answer (score 0):

for one renewal

after n days there is a $(1 - p)^n$ chance that the book is not reserved, each day it becomes reserves with probability p, and not reserved by prob (1-p) - so for n days the prob of not reserved is (1 - p) x (1 - p) x ...x (1-p), n times -

which is $(1 - p)^n probability

a renewal on day n extends the period of loan by n days (since the days to the end of the initial loan are already guaranteed)

so my formula for the expected loan duration, with one renewal on day n, is

$E(N) = 21 + (1 - p)^n \times n$

maximising with calculus

$dE/dn = 0 + log(1 - p) \times (1-p)^n + (1-p)^n$

find dE/dn = 0

$nlog(1 - p) \times (1-p)^n + (1-p)^n = 0 $

$(1-p)^n (nlog(1 - p) + 1) = 0 $

$ n = -1 / log (1 - p) $

so if the risk of reservation is 1/20

I make that the optimum renewal date is -1 / log(1 - 1/20) = -1 / -.051 = 20 (natural logs)

so renew on 20th day, then renew again after another 20 days